# How to do arithmetic operations in an outer query from an inner query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL and I am trying to build a query in access. I need to select the ratio of two columns that are smaller than the average ratio. 
I was able to first group the data to be able to get the total for each column.  I was also able to get the ratio of per group in the following (query which works):

```
SELECT col1, Ratio
FROM (
    SELECT ID, SUM(col3)/SUM(col4) AS Ratio 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY ID
)  AS Ratios 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON Ratios.ID=table2.ID
```

However, I want to display only those ratios for those that are smaller than the average ratio. I tried it this other way, and I get a message: "can't aggregate function in WHERE clause"

```
SELECT col1, Ratio
FROM (
    SELECT ID, SUM(col3)/SUM(col4) AS Ratio 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY ID
)  AS Ratios 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON Ratios.ID=table2.ID
WHERE Ratio<AVG(Ratio)
```

Could anyone help me see what am I doing wrong, I have been working on this for a few hours and honestly I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a painful query in Access. You can do it like this:

```
SELECT col1, Ratio
FROM (SELECT ID, SUM(col3)/SUM(col4) AS Ratio 
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY ID
     )  AS Ratios INNER JOIN
     table2 
     ON Ratios.ID = table2.ID
WHERE Ratio < (select AVG(Ratio)
               from (SELECT ID, SUM(col3)/SUM(col4) AS Ratio 
                     FROM table1 
                     GROUP BY ID
                    ) as t
              );
```

EDIT:

Yes, you could do this with a `having` clause but it would have to be embedded in the subquery:

```
SELECT col1, Ratio
FROM (SELECT ID, SUM(col3)/SUM(col4) AS Ratio 
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING SUM(col3)/SUM(col4) < (select AVG(Ratio)
                                    from (SELECT ID, SUM(col3)/SUM(col4) AS Ratio 
                                          FROM table1 
                                          GROUP BY ID
                                         ) as t
                                   )
     )  AS Ratios INNER JOIN
     table2 
     ON Ratios.ID = table2.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that did it! Could I have used the HAVING clause to build this query?  Thanks again!